# How to cope with an multi language system with pulldowns?

Tags: php, mysql, internationalization

I have builded an system with php an MySQL. This has been set as multi language, so each user can choose it's own language. How do I work with pulldowns?

Most of these menus are generated from the database. How would you make this work for an multi language system?

Comment: your question is difficult to understand.. are you trying to build a dropdown box based on the user's language preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database generated string would simply be used as a parameter to [gettext](https://www.php.net/gettext), which would then chose a translated string if one was available for the selected language. If one isn't available, it would default to the provided string.

Comment: Would you store only the KEY in the Database, then pull the value, based on language, from a resource bundle?

Comment: Could you please expand on how to mine the keys in the DB in order to compile a dictionary to translate? Because adding them to `.po` file by hand will be somewhat hard..